# Bootstrap responsive columns order based on alphabetical content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

Let's say I have 4 columns like this

```
A   D   G   J
B   E   H   K
C   F   I   L
```

I just can't get my head around the markup that's needed to let it flow like this:

```
A   G
B   H
C   I
D   J
E   K
F   L
```

Instead of

```
A   D
B   E
C   F
G   J
H   K
I   L
```

Any information regarding this issue would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you will be able to achieve this with bootstrap. Why not put the Letters in their correct order: A B C D /linebreak E F G H...

Comment: Are you asking to change the columns on a different viewport?

Comment: Yes, Sorry! 
Basically what I want is that when viewing it on a large screen, all 4 are next to each other
When on a tablet, you get 2 columns and on a phone, all of them are underneath each other, respecting the sorting (alphabetically)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">A<br>B<br>C</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-md-push-3">G<br>H<br>I</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-md-pull-3">D<br>E<br>F</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">J<br>K<br>L</div>
```

I find designing from the smallest size first make this easy.

**[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/o50JgIcctM)**

Comment: I think this should be accepted as the correct answer, as it is the most elegant and straightforward answer.

Comment: Anonymous coward downvoter care to grow a pair and comment?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. Note - this is 2 columns at less than 768px and 4 at 768px and up.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/663/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div>A</div>
            <div>B</div>
            <div>C</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div>D</div>
            <div>E</div>
            <div>F</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div>G</div>
            <div>H</div>
            <div>I</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div>J</div>
            <div>K</div>
            <div>L</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using bootstrap 3. I have achieved the effect I think you are after by nesting columns:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
 <div class="col-md-6">A <br/> B <br/> C</div>
 <div class="col-md-6">D <br/> E <br/> F</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6"> 
  <div class="col-md-6">G <br/> H <br/> I</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">J <br/> K <br/> L</div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/Qk8Fbw8PqE)